# How to extract the text from several elements with the same class to a string, change the text and put them text back in each original location?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wonder if there is any way to get all the text of the elements with the same class

Example:

```
<div class = "tochange"> Text to change - 1 </div>
     <h3 class = "tochange"> Text to change - 2 </h3>

<div class = "tochange"> Text to change - 3 </div>

<select class = "tochange"> Text to change - 1 </select>
     <option class = "tochange"> Text to change - 4 </option>
     <option class = "tochange"> Text to change - 5 </option>
     <option class = "tochange"> Text to change - 6 </option>
     <option class = "tochange"> Text to change - 7 </option>

<span class = "tochange"> Text to change - 8 </>

<script>
  var arrayFromClass = [];
$ ('.tochange'). each (function () {
     arrayFromClass.push (this.innerText);
});
  var ArrayToString = arrayFromClass.toString();
</script>
```

Change each of these texts and then put them back in the original DOM

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you want:

```js
const modifyAll = ()=>{
  [...document.querySelectorAll('.tochange')].map(el=>{
    el.innerHTML='FOO'+el.innerHTML;
  });
};
setTimeout(_=>{
  modifyAll();
},1000)
```

```html
<div class="tochange"> Text to change - 1 </div>
<h3 class="tochange"> Text to change - 2 </h3>

<div class="tochange"> Text to change - 3 </div>

<select class="tochange"> Text to change - 1 </select>
<option class="tochange"> Text to change - 4 </option>
<option class="tochange"> Text to change - 5 </option>
<option class="tochange"> Text to change - 6 </option>
<option class="tochange"> Text to change - 7 </option>

<span class="tochange"> Text to change - 8</span>
```

Comment: Interesting.
Thank you very much for the quick answer.

I will try to implement it.
Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

You can get all the texts by using `$(this).text()` in `jquery` which is given below and change those simply like this:

```js
$('.tochange').each(function () {
    // console.log($(this).text()); // Will print all the texts from "tochange" class
    $(this).text("New Added Text");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tochange"> Text to change - 1 </div>
<h3 class="tochange"> Text to change - 2 </h3>

<div class="tochange"> Text to change - 3 </div>

<select class="tochange"> Text to change - 1 </select>
<option class="tochange"> Text to change - 4 </option>
<option class="tochange"> Text to change - 5 </option>
<option class="tochange"> Text to change - 6 </option>
<option class="tochange"> Text to change - 7 </option>

<span class="tochange"> Text to change - 8 </span>
```

If you would like to change every text in your way, just add an extra field in your tag with that specific text and change like this:

```js
$('.tochange').each(function () {
    // console.log($(this).text());
    $(this).text($(this).data('desc'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tochange" data-desc="Hello.."> Text to change - 1 </div>
<h3 class="tochange" data-desc="How are you?"> Text to change - 2 </h3>

<div class="tochange" data-desc="I'm fine.."> Text to change - 3 </div>

<select class="tochange"> Text to change - 1 </select>
<option class="tochange"> Text to change - 4 </option>
<option class="tochange"> Text to change - 5 </option>
<option class="tochange"> Text to change - 6 </option>
<option class="tochange"> Text to change - 7 </option>

<span class="tochange"> Text to change - 8 </span>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, Shahnawaz Hossan.
In reality, each text will be modified by a unique one.
For example "text - 1" will be "Hello", "text 2" will be "How are you?"
That way I can't replace them with a single text with $ (this) .text ().

Comment: You can do that as well, like you need to add an extra attribute for that. If you would like to see I can help with that.

Comment: @hlguiw, have a look at my second answer I've updated. You can achieve what you would like to implement in that way.

Comment: Any help is welcome. Thank you so much!
I'm having trouble with a translation API for a website I'm trying to do. If you can take a look at the other question on that subject, I would be very grateful.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63016950/how-to-translate-only-one-htmldiv

Comment: This is also quite interesting. I am already thinking of some uses for this.
Would it be possible to use it, in some way, in the problem described in the other question?

Comment: I've to see that question first actually, ok let me have a look at that, please.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218379/discussion-between-hlguiw-and-shahnawaz-hossan).

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be to use `.text(function)`. If as an example all you wanted is to surround the text with `[]` the all you would need is:

```
$('.tochange').text(function() {
    return '[' + this.textContent + ']';
});
```

```js
$('.tochange').text(function() {
    return '[' + this.textContent + ']';
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tochange"> Text to change - 1 </div>
<h3 class="tochange"> Text to change - 2 </h3>

<div class="tochange"> Text to change - 3 </div>

<select class="tochange"> Text to change - 1 </select>
<option class="tochange"> Text to change - 4 </option>
<option class="tochange"> Text to change - 5 </option>
<option class="tochange"> Text to change - 6 </option>
<option class="tochange"> Text to change - 7 </option>

<span class="tochange"> Text to change - 8</span>
```

If, however, what you want is to have the text in an array then here's how:

```
var arrayFromClass = $('.tochange').map(function() {
    return this.textContent;
})
.get();
```

```js
var arrayFromClass = $('.tochange').map(function() {
    return this.textContent;
})
.get();

console.log( arrayFromClass );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tochange"> Text to change - 1 </div>
<h3 class="tochange"> Text to change - 2 </h3>

<div class="tochange"> Text to change - 3 </div>

<select class="tochange"> Text to change - 1 </select>
<option class="tochange"> Text to change - 4 </option>
<option class="tochange"> Text to change - 5 </option>
<option class="tochange"> Text to change - 6 </option>
<option class="tochange"> Text to change - 7 </option>

<span class="tochange"> Text to change - 8</span>
```